# Recent activity display should show capped vs. uncapped rep as a hover effect

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity, reputation-display

With the recent change to completely exempt accepted answers from the rep cap, it is now harder to use the recent activity display to figure out how close you are to the daily rep cap.  It used to be that you could assume that as long as you were below 200 you hadn't capped yet.  Once you hit 200 you knew that you had to get accepted answers to add more rep that day.  Now, you can be over 200 for the day, yet not have hit the cap if the 200 includes rep from accepted answers.

To address this issue, I propose that the hover over for the rep value on the recent activity show the breakdown between rep points that are subject to the cap (normal question/answer votes) and accepted answers.  This provides a quick and convenient means to get at this information.  The alternative to is to hand calculate the points from reputation by viewing your reputation activity for the day, totaling the accepted answer points manually, and subtracting these from the actual reputation displayed.

Answer (score 5):

Totally seconded, and good solution.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think this is necessary.  Someone please code up a Greasemonkey script for it; don't waste time with it here.

Seriously, the new rules make it *easier* to eyeball your daily rep-cap, not *harder*.  Look through your daily activity; subtract 15 from the daily total for each accepted answer; subtract any bounties won; and you're left with your daily cappable rep.  You don't need to consider what order you were upvoted or downvoted -- it's just simple arithmatic now.

Personally I find some users' concern over rep-cap and who's hitting it and who isn't ... well, childish.  If *that* is the motivating factor over whether you answer a question or not, well, I'm sincerely *unimpressed* with your reasons for being here and participating in this site.  **Thus, I would prefer that the site's recent activities page continue in it's generic reporting of daily reputation.** If the rep-cap-obsessed need more info than the system provides, let them figure it out for themselves.

Comment: @quack: I think the rep cap is often a positive incentive to answer another couple of question before calling it a day.

Comment: -1 the interface should make it easier to play the game whether you agree with the object of the game or not.  also, simple curiosity is sufficient reason to make this easier to find than not.

Comment: ~quack don't judge other people, everyone has their reasons and maybe you shouldn't care so much about others. Look at the results, not the motivating factor.

Comment: @Kop: i'm offering an opinion on a proposed feature request; i'm not judging anybody specifically.  what results?  that this has been downvoted?  i'm shocked, i tell you, shocked.

Comment: ~quack, I meant look at the results people obtain, not what motivates them. If someone motivated by rep gives good answer, then it's the only thing that matters.